# Insert data into multiples tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an excel file file that some data need to be inserted into *Table1* and some other data into *Table2* or *Table3*.
I Already have my routes,models, controllers for each table.

As I have to do one function to insert data into all tables, I don't know if I need to do it inside a Model. Also I don't know how to do it, how designate the right data to the right table.

*Edit: More specific*

I have a `file input` and a `button` inside my view. When I select the excel file with the `input` and press the `button` I need to read the data AND insert that data into my database. The problem here is that this data will go to different tables. I would know solve this if all data would go to a single table, but I have no idea how to divide the data to separte tables.

Should I call a function from `controller` inside the `view` ? If so which `Controller` use ? Or maybe a function from model, but again which `Model` should I use ? Since each table has it's own `Model`.

Do I need to use JQuery to make an `Ajax` then direct it to a certain route so that route would call a `Controller`'s function that would make the inserts?
I Dont think so because all data manipulation should be inside a `View`, right ?

Comment: @Mysteryos I'm not a lazzy guy who wants everything easy. But I really don't know how to start. I have the models and I can CRUD every single model separeted. But I don't know where/how I would do that with multiple tables. Should I create an exclusive model for that ?? Do these tables MUST have a relation ? Maybe a tip for start ??

Comment: @Mysteryos If you don't want to tell me how-to-do. Could at least give me a hint and tell me what to do. Like what is the right way (use JS function, call controllers function etc...).

Comment: Ok. If the tables are related by foreign keys, you gotta setup your relationship. Read: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships
As for your view, you need to have your `input` inside a form whose action is a `POST`. Read: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp Then you gotta have a route in your controller that takes the excel file from the `POST` method, and sends it to a method that parses the file(see library: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel for reading excel files). That method returns all information from the excel in a structured array. Take that info n save it

Comment: Your question is just too broad to be answered. A better way to help you would be that you upload the code on github, and i can annonate the methods from there.

Comment: @Mysteryos That would be amazing man. I'll do that. So the flow is:  Select  file from `View` -> form that `post` to a `Route` -> The route redirects me to a method inside my `Controller` ?? I'll post the github link as soon as possible.

Comment: Alright. Awaiting your link. Seems like you got lost between the frontend and the backend.